# Install library with relative path to make it portable?

Tags: shell, shared-libraries

I'm trying to install `libimobiledevice` in such a way that it can easily be moved to a different directory. I'm installing libimobiledevice inside an Atom Electron app. Unfortunately, ./configure expands any --prefix environment variables I set. For example, if I use --prefix `${PWD}/libimobiledevice`, it gets installed to `/Users/MyName/libimobiledevice`, with all the paths hard-wired into the executable. This is fine for running libimobiledevice in `/Users/MyName`, but it doesn't work if I try to move it to `/Users/AnotherUser` on a different machine. This is the code I'm using

```
LIB_PATH="libimobiledevice"

[ -d "$LIB_PATH" ] && rm -rf $LIB_PATH

mkdir $LIB_PATH

cd $LIB_PATH

LIB_PATH=${PWD}
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$LIB_PATH/lib/pkgconfig"

PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$LIB_PATH/lib/pkgconfig" ./autogen.sh
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$LIB_PATH/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure --prefix=$LIB_PATH #--enable-debug-code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post answered my question: [How to copy and relink binaries on osx](http://thecourtsofchaos.com/2013/09/16/how-to-copy-and-relink-binaries-on-osx/)

I checked with `otool` and changed the path of the linked libraries using `@executable_path`